# django-haystack: object has no attribute 'Indexable'

Tags: django, django-haystack

Iam new to django-haystack, and I am trying to follow the getting started guide. However, I encounter an AttributeError: object has no attribute 'Indexable'.

In my settins.py, I have:

```
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'mysite.search_sites'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'solr'
HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr'
```

In my models.py (which resides in my app called "searchapp"), I have:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class baymodel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=765, db_column='Domain', blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=765, db_column='Category', blank=True) 
    link = models.CharField(max_length=765, db_column='Link') 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=765, db_column='Name', blank=True) 
    cur_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

    def index_queryset(self):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
       return self.objects.all()
```

In my search_indexes.py (residing in my searchapp directory), I then have:

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from searchapp.models import baymodel


class baymodelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
    link = indexes.CharField(model_attr='link')
    domain = indexes.CharField(model_attr='domain')
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='cur_timestamp')

def get_model(self):
    return baymodel

site.register(baymodel, baymodelIndex)
```

In search_sites.py, I have:

```
import haystack
haystack.autodiscover()
```

I have installed solr according to their instructions, and I can see the pretty solr admin page.

Now, when I do:

```
sudo python manage.py build_solr_schema
```

I get thrown an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Indexable'
```

I have tried to do:

```
python ./manage.py shell
```

and I again get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Indexable'
```

If I simply go into python and try and import haystack, I get:

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import haystack
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("You must define the HAYSTACK_SITECONF setting before using the search framework.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You must define the HAYSTACK_SITECONF  setting before using the search framework.
```

which is strange because my settings.py does specify HAYSTACK_CONF and python ./manage.py shell throws an AttributeError.

Has anyone encountered a similar error? Thanks.

Comment: Which version have you installed?  It looks like you have installed the latest release but are using the development docs - so it would be class BayModelIndex(SearchIndex): intsead - http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-haystack/en/v1.2.4/searchindex_api.html#quick-start

Comment: Hi James: when I look into the .egg files, I see Version: 1.2.6. When I use BayModelIndex(SearchIndex) it throws me a NameError on SearchIndex [NameError: name 'SearchIndex' is not defined].

Comment: Are you importing SearchIndex correctly? from haystack.indexes import SearchIndex

Comment: James: thanks a tonne. I used indexes.SearchIndex and that has solved it. However, when I export my schema.xml, then use python manage.py rebuild_index and restart solr, I see the page but search returns no results. When I do  ./manage.py haystack_info I get "Loaded URLconf to initialize SearchSite...Main site registered 0 index(es)." i.e it is not indexing anything. Any clues as to why this could be happening. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped. In BayModelIndex you don't seem to have index_queryset defined, which gets the list of objects?

Comment: James: I have edited my code to include index_queryset, but I still have 0 indexes.Should it be get_queryset or index_queryset? I tried both, and they give 0 indexes when I rebuild index. BTW: which documentation do you use for haystack 1.6? All the links to 1.6 docs seems dead :(

Comment: James: Actually, when I rebuild index, I get: [AttributeError: 'baymodelIndex' object has no attribute 'objects'].. Strange..

Comment: You would want BayModel.objects not the 'baymodelIndex.objects. It just needs to return a normal orm query.

Comment: James, I understand that it requires BayModel.objects. But, where does one specify the index_queryset? Isnt that in BayModelIndex? or should it be in the models.py file? What is wrong with how I have specified index_queryset in BayModelIndex? Thanks again.

Comment: AttributeError: 'baymodelIndex' object has no attribute 'objects' suggests that somewhere you are trying to call baymodelIndex.objects?

Comment: Thanks James.. That has solved the problem. Was struggling with this for about 2 days now. If you could post it as an answer, Id be glad to accept it.

Comment: James.. Just a quick question: Although everything indexes and there are no errors whatsoever, I get no results :( whatever I search for. Any clues?

Comment: At a guess i would first check your template text template (use_template=True), is the location correct? does it defined correct BayModel fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code is based on haystack 2 which is in development, v2 changes the way indexes are defined. Installed version is 1.2 so the correct documents are [available here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-haystack/en/v1.2.4/searchindex_api.html#quick-start), e.g.

```
class BayModelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
```

should be (with correct import of SearchIndex):

```
class BayModelIndex(SearchIndex):
```

also instead of `get_model`, the index class needs `index_queryset` defined, which should return a QuerySet.

Comment: its weird, when i click on latest, I still get old documentation. I have explicitly click on 1.2.7